# Processing MongoDB data using Mrjob on Amazon EMR

Tags: python, mongodb, hadoop, amazon-emr, mrjob

I know that Mrjob uses Hadoop Streaming. I also know that there is a [plugin](http://api.mongodb.org/hadoop/Hadoop+Streaming+Support.html) for using MongoDB with Hadoop Streaming. However, I couldn't find any examples on bringing two together.

Is this (at least in theory) possible? If so, are there any relevant examples or tutorials? Note that I'm open to extending Mrjob library or even falling back to Boto.